# confused with accessing variable in batch apex

Tags: apex, batch, relationships

Got a little confused while trying to access a variable in my batch. I update a certain field on Contact based upon the LOB field as queried for in my initial query (line 2). However, when I later try to include that field in an if statement I get an error. Here's my code-

```java
global class batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful, Schedulable{
    global String query = 'SELECT ID, Policy_r.Product_Name_r.LOB__c FROM PAO__c WHERE Date__c = YESTERDAY';
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {       
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<PAO__c> scope) { 
    for(Custom__c custom : [SELECT Id, Contact__c, PAO__c, POA__r.field_i_need__c FROM Custom__c WHERE POA__c IN :scope])            
            conIdSet.add(custom.Contact__c);
            updateConsMap.put(custom.Contact__c, custom);
        }
    
    List<Contact> conList= new List<Contact>([SELECT Id, field_to_update__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :conIdSet]);
    
    if(!conIdSet.isEmpty()) {
        for(Contact con :conList) {
        /* line below is where i'm stuck! */
        if (Policy_r.Product_Name_r.LOB__c.Contains('Fixed'))
           con.field_to_update__c = updateConsMap.get(con.Id).Policy_Allocation_Option__r.Performance_Lock_Date__c;
        }

        update conList;
    }
```

The error I'm getting is `Variable does not exist: Policy_r`. What is the proper way to access this field to include it in the if statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, relationship fields use double underscore

```
Policy__r.xxxx
```

Your batchable execute() method receives a list of `PAD__c` which is where the `Policy__r.Product_Name__r.LOB__c` field can be found

But your for loop

```
for (Contact con: conlist) { ..}
```

is looping over contacts, not `PAD__c` and the only way you'll be able to reference a PAD__c is if you can associate a contact to a PAD__c.

The way one handles this is with a Map.  You appear to be doing this in this line:

```
updateConsMap.put(custom.Contact__c, custom);
```

which appears to be a map of `Custom__c`'s by ContactId

*(my first suggestion is that all maps should be named by what they are: `customsByContactId`).  This makes code so much easier to read and debug*

You'll need a map `padsById` that you build as

```
Map<Id,PAD__c> padsById = new Map<Id,PAD__c> (scope);
```

So, now, in your for loop:

```
for (Contact con: conList) {
   Custom__c custom = customsByContactId.get(con.Id);
   if (padsById.containsKey(custom.PAD__c) &&
       padsById.get(custom.PAD__c).Policy__r.Product_Name__r.LOB__c.contains('Fixed') ) { ...}
}
```

Comment: i get the same error even when i add a second underscore

Comment: more complete answer - updated

Comment: this is genius! thank you so much.

Comment: hey question, don't i need to fill this map with a padsById.put(); somewhere prior to my loop?

Comment: `Map<Id,PAD__c> padsById = new Map<Id,PAD__c> (scope);` populates the map -- and yes, before the for loop

Comment: ok so i have the line `Map<Id,PAD__c> padsById = new Map<Id,PAD__c> (scope);` but while unit testing i've been getting a `NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object` error on the `if (padsById.containsKey(custom.PAD__c)...` line so i'm thinking the map is empty

Comment: I suggest posting a new question with your current batchable code + unit testing code so this can get resolved more quickly

Comment: i did and you actually commented on it, hahaha. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/329196/test-class-passing-but-not-covering-execute-method, i've traced it back to this line due to the map being empty