# test class passing but not covering execute method

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, code-coverage, map

I have coded a batch class and am now working on the corresponding unit test. I believe I've inserted all the objects I need but none of the actual execute method is being covered, despite the test passing. The other lines of code are being passed. Here's my class:

```
global class LastIndexLockDateByLOBBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful, Schedulable {
    global String query = 'SELECT ID, Policy__r.Product_Name__r.Product_LOB__c FROM Policy_Allocation_Option__c WHERE Performance_Lock_Date__c = YESTERDAY AND' + 
                       '(LastModifiedDate = YESTERDAY OR LastModifiedDate = TODAY)';
global Set<Id> processedCons; //to save processed contact Ids from previous batch

public LastIndexLockDateByLOBBatch() {
    processedCons = new Set<Id>();
}

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {       
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Policy_Allocation_Option__c> scope) { 
    Set<Id> conIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, Contact_Policy_Allocation__c> cpaByContactIdMap = new Map<Id, Contact_Policy_Allocation__c>();
    Map<Id, Policy_Allocation_Option__c> paoByIdMap = new Map<Id, Policy_Allocation_Option__c>(scope);
    
    for(Contact_Policy_Allocation__c cpa : [SELECT Id, Contact__c, Policy_Allocation_Option__c, Policy_Allocation_Option__r.Performance_Lock_Date__c FROM Contact_Policy_Allocation__c WHERE Policy_Allocation_Option__c IN :scope])            
        if(!processedCons.contains(cpa.Contact__c))  {  //skip already processed contacts
            conIdSet.add(cpa.Contact__c);
            cpaByContactIdMap.put(cpa.Contact__c, cpa);
        }
    
    List<Contact> conList= new List<Contact>([SELECT Id, Last_Fixed_Index_Lock_Date__c, Last_Life_Index_Lock_Date__c, Last_VA_Lock_Date__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :conIdSet]);
    
    if(!conIdSet.isEmpty()) {
        for(Contact con :conList) {
            Contact_Policy_Allocation__c cpa = cpaByContactIdMap.get(con.Id);
            if (paoByIdMap.containsKey(cpa.Policy_Allocation_Option__c) && paoByIdMap.get(cpa.Policy_Allocation_Option__c).Policy__r.Product_Name__r.Product_LOB__c.Contains('Fixed')) {
                con.Last_Fixed_Index_Lock_Date__c = cpaByContactIdMap.get(con.Id).Policy_Allocation_Option__r.Performance_Lock_Date__c;
            }
            
            if (paoByIdMap.containsKey(cpa.Policy_Allocation_Option__c) && paoByIdMap.get(cpa.Policy_Allocation_Option__c).Policy__r.Product_Name__r.Product_LOB__c.Contains('Life')) {
                con.Last_Life_Index_Lock_Date__c = cpaByContactIdMap.get(con.Id).Policy_Allocation_Option__r.Performance_Lock_Date__c;
            }                                
            if (paoByIdMap.containsKey(cpa.Policy_Allocation_Option__c) && paoByIdMap.get(cpa.Policy_Allocation_Option__c).Policy__r.Product_Name__r.Product_LOB__c.Contains('VA')) {
                con.Last_VA_Lock_Date__c = cpaByContactIdMap.get(con.Id).Policy_Allocation_Option__r.Performance_Lock_Date__c;
            }
        }
        
        update conList;
        processedCons.addAll(conIdSet); //add processed contacts to this list, if same contact present in next batch, it will be skipped
    }

}
  
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    system.debug('Final Processed : ' + processedCons); 
}  

public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    Database.executeBatch(this, 200);
}
}
```

And here is my test class:

```
@isTest
public class LastIndexLockDateByLOBBatchTest {

public static testmethod void LastIndexLockDateByLOBBatchTest() {
    
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = 'TestAccount';
    insert acc;        
    
    Contact con = new Contact();
    con.FirstName = 'Test Name';
    con.LastName = 'Test';
    con.AccountId = acc.Id;
    con.Last_Fixed_Index_Lock_Date__c = System.today();
    insert con;
           
    Policy__c p = new Policy__c();
    p.Name = '71629012';
    insert p;
    
    Campaign_Member_Policy__c cmp = new Campaign_Member_Policy__c();
    cmp.Policy__c = p.Id;
    cmp.Contact__c = con.Id;
    insert cmp;
    
    Policy_Allocation_Option__c pao = new Policy_Allocation_Option__c();
    pao.Policy__c = p.Id;
    pao.CreatedDate = System.today()-2;
    pao.LastModifiedDate = System.today();
    pao.Performance_Lock_Date__c = System.today();
    insert pao;
    
    Contact_Policy_Allocation__c cpa = new Contact_Policy_Allocation__c();
    cpa.Contact__c = con.Id;
    cpa.Policy_Allocation_Option__c = pao.Id;
    cpa.Campaign_Member_Policy__c = cmp.Id;
    insert cpa;
    
    Master_Product__c mp1 = new Master_Product__c();
    mp1.Name = 'TP1';
    mp1.Description__c = 'Test Product 1';
    mp1.Product_Line__c = 'Fixed';
    mp1.Active__c = TRUE;
    insert mp1;
    
    Master_Product__c mp2 = new Master_Product__c();
    mp2.Name = 'TP2';
    mp2.Description__c = 'Test Product 2';
    mp2.Product_Line__c = 'Life';
    mp2.Active__c = TRUE;
    insert mp2;
    
    Master_Product__c mp3 = new Master_Product__c();
    mp3.Name = 'TP3';
    mp3.Description__c = 'Test Product 3';
    mp3.Product_Line__c = 'VA';
    mp3.Active__c = TRUE;
    insert mp3;
    
    Test.startTest();
    LastIndexLockDateByLOBBatch lastIndexLock = new LastIndexLockDateByLOBBatch();
    String sch= '0 00 7 * * ? *';
    String jobid = System.schedule('Last Index Lock Date By LOB Batch', sch, lastIndexLock);
    Test.stopTest();
   }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why NONE of the execute class is being covered, not even the `public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Policy_Allocation_Option__c> scope) {` line. Any insight or help is extremely appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your data doesn't match the query in `start()`, so there's no records to iterate over in `execute()`.

```
Policy_Allocation_Option__c pao = new Policy_Allocation_Option__c();
pao.Performance_Lock_Date__c = System.today();
```

You set `Performance_Lock_Date__c` to today, but your query looks for

```
WHERE Performance_Lock_Date__c = YESTERDAY
```

---

Side note: without assertions about the behavior of the code, unit tests have very limited value.

Comment: @sfn00b this is addressed by [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines) which is a wealth of useful tips

Comment: That doesn't really make sense, which makes me suspect it is a red herring for some other change.

Answer (score 0):

Some other suggestions:

- Your testmethod is attempting to run two async events: the schedulable and then the batchable. SFDC will only execute 1 async within a test.startTest-test.stopTest bracket
- Your testmethod is constructing a CRON expression for no reason -- you don't need to verify that SFDC knows how to schedule jobs.

So ...

Redo the testmethod

```
 @Istest static void givenSchedulableVerifyBatchable() {
    // given mock data
    .. DML mock data such that batch start() finds it

    // given schedulable
    LastIndexLockDateByLOBBatch schedulable = new LastIndexLockDateByLOBBatch();

    // when executed by SFDC
    Test.startTest();
    SchedulableContext sc;
    schedulable.execute(sc);
    Test.stoptest();

    // Then verify actions of execute() and finish()  
    asserts go here
```

Also, your query can be simplified:

```
String query = 'SELECT ID, Policy__r.Product_Name__r.Product_LOB__c FROM Policy_Allocation_Option__c WHERE Performance_Lock_Date__c = YESTERDAY AND' + 
                   '(LastModifiedDate >= YESTERDAY)';
```

or, better still:

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {       
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT ID, Policy__r.Product_Name__r.Product_LOB__c 
                                      FROM Policy_Allocation_Option__c 
                                      WHERE Performance_Lock_Date__c = YESTERDAY AND
                                            LastModifiedDate >= YESTERDAY]);
}
```

and, unless you are doing managed packages, there is no reason to use `global` modifier, `public` is best practice